# Add Pandas column value based on ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following requirement with a sample csv file as below,

```
colA   colB    NewCol
 1     val1     val1
 1     val2     val1 + val2
 1     val3     val1 + val2 + val3
 2     val4     val4
 2     val5     val4 + val5
 2     val6     val4 + val5 + val6
 3     val7     val7
 3     val8     val7 + val8
 3     val9     val7 + val8 + val9
```

I want to add a new column to df, such that it add successive colB values only for same ID value. Col B can be Integer or String.

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` + `cumsum`:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('colA')['colB'].cumsum()
```

---

For summing strings, you can use a list comprehension with `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values('colA')

df['C'] = [''.join(g.iloc[:i+1].values) \
           for _, g in df.groupby('colA')['colB'] \
           for i in range(len(g.index))]

print(df)

   colA  colB             C
0     1  val1          val1
1     1  val2      val1val2
2     1  val3  val1val2val3
3     2  val4          val4
4     2  val5      val4val5
5     2  val6  val4val5val6
6     3  val7          val7
7     3  val8      val7val8
8     3  val9  val7val8val9
```

**Explanation**

- First iterate `groupby` elements via `for _, g in df.groupby(...)[...]`. We ignore the index `_` here as we are only interested in the values.
- Then iterate `range(len(g.index))`, i.e. iterate over the number of items in the group.
- Apply `''.join` on the first `i` values. We use `g.iloc[:i+1]` to extract the first `i` values in a group.
- Wrap all the above in a nested list comprehension.

Comment: @AsheshNair, Can you clarify what you mean? Will `colB` be all integers, all strings, or a mixture? Do you want to add `1 + 1 + 'c' = '11c'`? Or `2 + 3 = '23'`? How would you add an integer to string?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, ColB will be string - a + b = 'ab'

Comment: thanks , that work's perfectly. Trying to understand your code

Comment: @AsheshNair, I added an explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) or `pd.Series.cumsum` what perfectly working with numeric and strings:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('colA')['colB'].apply(np.cumsum)
```

Or:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('colA')['colB'].apply(pd.Series.cumsum)

print (df)
   colA  colB        NewCol
0     1  val1          val1
1     1  val2      val1val2
2     1  val3  val1val2val3
3     2  val4          val4
4     2  val5      val4val5
5     2  val6  val4val5val6
6     3  val7          val7
7     3  val8      val7val8
8     3  val9  val7val8val9
```